# Lightroom Batch HDR Script

Tags: merge, adobe, photoshop, hdr, lightroom

I don't have a lot or any experience in coding.

I'm looking to Batch Merge HDR photographs in lightroom CC for OSX. More specifically automate the Batch Process.

The task:

Select 3 bracketed photos in Lightroom from exposure -3 to +3
use Photomerge HDR function ( control + shift + H ) - this creates a merged photograph file in the catalogue right after the 3 bracketed photos.

From there, the process would continue - selecting the next three and Merging the HDR photo until all photos in the catalogue have been processed.

I've looked up on Adobe Forums and have had no luck automating the process, right now manually doing this takes a lot of time...

Answer (score 0):

You're right. There's no way to do the HDR processing in batch at the moment.

But let Adobe know you're interested here:
https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/batch-hdr?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all

And see 
https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/batch-hdr

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for years and found the following semi automatic solution:

1. Go into the folder that you want to batch process the HDRs
2. in the Menu go to **Photo -> Stacking -> Auto-Stack by Capture Time**
3. Set the time between the stacks and click **Stack**
4. You now have your stacks of bracketed Exposures
5. Select all stacks (Lightroom is smart enough that it won't try to marge all stacks as HDR but just the photos within the stacks)
6. Merge the photos within the stacks as HDR (**control + shift + H**)